# How can i transfer large amount of transaction from android device to server?

Tags: android

I am currently storing my transactions in SqLite DB if there is no internet connection at the moment and when there is internet available i send the pending transactions with the new one made so making it quite a lot of data and a lot of API hits which chokes the device and it becomes unresponsive. So need help with a proper way to sync these transactions to the server. Also these are being sended to a Socket as well as a Server.

I tried using AsyncTask for it but it also causes problems if transactions are above 200. Tried Retrofit for it and to some extent the count exceeded from 200 to almost 350 but the issue and unresponsivness remains.

Comment: I presume you are making 200-300 actual requests. Instead of sending all the data in separate requests you can speed it up quite a bit by creating batches with a bunch of datarows and sending them as one request. Though you'd have to support this on the server as well. Other than that, you can try introducing delays between the requests. Either way, the whole device shouldn't become unresponsive because you are doing http requests. Are you doing some kind of calculation on the data before sending?

Comment: why don't you send all data at once in the form of JsonArray.

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to PriorityJobScheduler lib or WorkManager from JetPack.
When there is no network connection you can queue those request and those request will be send ones network connection is available. (So you dont need to wait until someone made new transaction to send old queued data too)

Also, in your current scenario, rather than sending single request for each transaction, ask your API Guy to accept request in List of object format. So you just need to create list of request body object and send to server